# Layout in unanswered questions looks a bit clunky

Tags: feature-request, design

A minor design critique: The bottom part of an unanswered question looks slightly inelegant, mainly because of the duplicate use of the icon.

Maybe it's worth getting rid of the icon in this specific case?

[image]

Comment: It's not only that... search for the design proposal and go over the comments :)

Comment: Sorry for the late response. I'm looking into this.